# Is my solution to prevent leakage between power rails correct?

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, voltage-divider

I have two boards with identical comparator circuitry (shown below). I want to detect in each board when the other is plugged in. My concern (in the picture) is that when I connect the two boards if the VDDA and VDDB are at different potentials (i.e., for example, one is at 12V and the other is at 10V), there would be leakage from VDDA to VDDB or vice versa.

Two questions:

1. Is my concern valid?
2. In order to work around this problem, I added the diodes D1. Would D1 solve this problem here?

UPDATED CIRCUIT with Component Values:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you think this would work even if the voltages were exactly matched? Your schematic is missing dots on the junctions making it difficult to read. There is no ground connection shown between the two boards. Is there one? Is the purpose of the comparator only to detect connection?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. There is a GROUND connection between the two boards. I updated the picture with ground and also dots to show where wires are connected.

Comment: How does PRES = 4 V when companion not plugged in?

Comment: @Transistor Good catch, that was a typo. PRES will be 4V when companion board **IS** plugged in, and 6V when companion board **NOT** plugged in.

Comment: OK. How does PRES = 4 V when companion board **IS** plugged in?

Comment: @Transistor When companion board is plugged in R2 on left board is in parallel with R2 on the right board (to the same ground), so effective pull-down is 5k (since each R1 and R2 are 10k). So far each of the boards (left and right), the PRES = 12*(5/(5+10)) = 4V.
Thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts are that you have two 10k pull-ups in parallel too. So now you have 5k on top and 5k on the bottom. No change in \$ V_{PRES} \$.

Comment: @Transistor - Correct, but the effective 5k on top is what I am trying to avoid with the use of the Diode D1. Let's say from the VDDA perspective (i.e. board on the left), wouldn't the only resistances in play be R1 (on left board) and two R2s? 
**Wouldn't the R1 on the right board not be part of the circuit because of the D1 on the right board?**

Comment: No. Current will flow from top to bottom through both diodes. Try it in the CircuitLab simulator's DC Solver. The button is on the editor toolbar. You don't need an account.

Comment: @Transistor Thank you I will do that. I will also mark your solution as the answer, although it proposes a completely different methodology. I am a bit concerned about the timing issues that might arise with that approach, but I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating it by introducing analog into the scheme.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0olJk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. If two GPIOs are available a digital check can take place between adjacent boards using an L (left) and R (right) pin.*

R-pin code:

- Enable internal pull-up on R.
- Configure R as output and set high.
- Send a 1 ms low pulse out on R.
- Configure R as input.
- If R is pulled low in the next 2 ms then there is a board to the right. Set the 'board to the right' flag in code.
- Loop back to the start.

L-pin code:

- On detection of a falling edge on L:
- Set the 'board to the left' flag in code.
- Wait a little (to allow the R on the other board to become an input).
- Configure L as output.
- Pull low for 1 ms.
- Configure L as input.
- Loop back to the start.

You'll need to clear the flags if you hear nothing from the other board after a time.

Comment: Please unaccept for a day or two as it discourages other answers and half the world has been asleep while we discussed this. You might get a better one!

Answer (score 0):

That isn’t going to work. Each board will detect its own Vdd, regardless of the other being plugged in. You’ll need two pins, one for each board to detect the other. I’d suggest putting a pull-up resistor on the defection side and connect the opposite side to ground. The detect pin will be high until the other board is attached, then will go low.

Comment: I updated my circuit with component values and stating the high and low status for the Output of the Comparator in addition to voltage levels. Does this change your mind?
*PS: I know how typical presence detection is done. I am trying to come up with a way to have many boards daisy chained and have them detect present on both sides*.